# ERROR #1063 Error mismatch error is

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I use an array for the fighters and the bullets

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

public class level extends MovieClip {

    var fighters:Array;
    var bullets:Array;

    public function level() {
        trace("level");
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        bullets=new Array();
        fighters=new Array();
    }

    function loop(e:Event) {
        if(numChildren<3) {
            var f=new fighter();
            addChild(f);
            // fighter spaWNS RANDOMLY
            f.x=Math.random()*stage.stageWidth;
            f.y=Math.random()*stage.stageHeight;
            f.rotation=Math.random()*360;
            fighters.push(f);
        }

        for(var bcount=bullets.length-1; bcount>=0; bcount--) {
            bullets[bcount].update();
            if(bullets[bcount].parent==null) {
                bullets.splice(bcount,1);
                bcount--;
            }
        }

        for(var count=fighters.length-1; count>=0; count--) {

//**** error is here
//**** there is a mismatch in the arguments with the fighter

            fighters[count].update();

            for(bcount=bullets.length-1; bcount>=0; bcount--) {
                if(fighters[count].hitTestObject(bullets[bcount])) {
                    fighters[count].health--;
                    removeChild(bullets[bcount]);
                    bullets.splice(bcount,1);
                }
            }

          if(fighters[count].health<=0) {
              removeChild(fighters[count]);
              fighters.splice(count,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Error #1063 means you didn't pass the required arguments or passed more than expected.  There was probably additional info on the error that you didn't post that could have helped and it most likely looked something like:

ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on •class and function•. Expected 1, got 0

Check the update() function for the fighter() object and see if it needs a param.